# Image Processing: I would like to filter pictures of a album containing specific text and numbers. Any tips/tools? (Ubuntu/Windows/Mac)

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I got huge collection of pictures, but need to filter the ones with specific text.  Tried few OCR tools from Five Best Text Recognition Tools but not helping my cause.. any tools/tip would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for the attention :)

Comment: If commonly available OCR tools don't do the job, it's highly unlikely that a home-brew solution can do any better. If you posted a sample image we might be able to suggest ways to make the OCR work better.

Comment: If you're looking for a tool, it might behoove you to mention the exact ones that you've tried before.

Comment: In order to effectively apply OCR tools, you generally have to (fully) eliminate all the non-text parts of an image. Can you include some examples of your images ? It might be easy or hard to extract what you want, but it depends on how are your images.

Comment: hi, 
many thanks for the reply.. 

Tools i tried => abby fine reader, evernote,etc as listed in http://lifehacker.com/5624781/five-best-text-recognition-tools they are pretty good in image=>searchable-text conversion.

my intention is: i got 500 photos in a folder. Need to chose images  containing certain text in it.. (will share sample)

Comment: How do you know they are pretty good in "image=>searchable-text conversion" ? The state of the art in that task has a f-score below 70%, and I see no research papers mentioned there to give any hope about the quality of these OCR tools.